# $_GET['updated'] does not work in Wordpress 3.1?

Tags: php

I tried the Satoshi Theme in Wordpress 3.1 and when the Theme Options are saved, they do get saved but the "Satoshi Options Saved."  message is not displayed. (the message is displayed in Wordpress 3.0.4).

**functions.php:**

```
/* -- Theme Options Page -- */
function theme_options_admin() {
    $option_fields = array();
    if ( $_GET['updated'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>Satoshi Options Saved.</p></div>';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/styles/functions.css" />';
?>

<div class="wrap">

    <h2>Satoshi Options</h2>

    <div id="message"></div>

    <div class="metabox-holder">

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>

            <div id="theme-options">

                <div id="left-column">
                    <?php
                        include("options/custom-logo.php");
                        include("options/custom-intro.php");
                        include("options/frontpage-headline.php");
                        include("options/featured-project.php");
                    ?>
                </div><!--end left-column-->
                <div id="right-column">
                    <?php
                        include("options/contact-details.php");
                        include("options/footer-text.php");
                        include("options/google-analytics.php");
                    ?>
                </div><!--end right-column-->

            </div><!--theme-options-->

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="<?php echo implode(",", $option_fields); ?>" />

        </form>
    </div><!--end metabox-holder-->
</div><!--end wrap-->
<?php
}
add_action('admin_menu', "theme_options_admin_init");
function theme_options_admin_init()
{
    add_theme_page( "Satoshi Theme Options", "Theme Options", 8, __FILE__, 'theme_options_admin');
}
```

Comment: Adding a comment so you spot the update, have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong, i couldn't even get the theme options page up without changing it..

```
add_theme_page( "Satoshi Theme Options", "Theme Options", 8, __FILE__, 'theme_options_admin');
```

Update that to read something like..

```
add_theme_page( "Satoshi Theme Options", "Theme Options", 8, 'satoshi-theme-options', 'theme_options_admin');
```

Saving options did produce the updated message as expected.

***UPDATE:** Looks like the `$_GET` key has changed in 3.1 when performing settings updates.*

*Update the following line.*

```
if ( $_GET['updated'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>Satoshi Options Saved.</p></div>';
```

*To..*

```
if ( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>Satoshi Options Saved.</p></div>';
```

*And you'll now see the updated message when saving.*

Comment: Hi again! I used your code but the message still not appearing in Wordpress 3.1

Comment: Yes sorry, i tested the wrong version, i'll go check now.. ;) **EDIT:** Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you always answer my questions, are you Wordpress developer or what.

Comment: I'm just a coder(coding is a hobby) that loves to use WordPress. Nothing special, just a guy with a hobby!... ;) Happy to help in any case.